# PHP: mysql setting up a login

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm super confused,
my code outputs this:

> posted login: login
>
> posted password: pass
>
> database login: login
>
> database pass: pass
>
> database id: 1
>
> database user: IDKMyName
>
> database creator: True
>
> database admin: True
>
> database master: True
>
> failed

Main part is the last line "failed", it should say logged in go. The posted user and database user is the same and posted pass is same so idk.

ps. the echos are just there for debugging not going to be in final code.

```
 <?php

session_start();

$db_login = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_id = "";
$db_user = "";
$db_creator = "";
$db_admin = "";
$db_master = "";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "main_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$submitlogin = $_POST['user'];
$submitpass = $_POST['password'];

$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE login = '$submitlogin' && pass = '$submitpass'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

if ($query) {
   while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
       $db_login = $row['login'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_pass = $row['pass'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_id = $row['ID'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_user = $row['user'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_creator = $row['creator'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_admin = $row['admin'] . PHP_EOL;
       $db_master = $row['master'] . PHP_EOL;
   }
}

echo "posted login: " . $submitlogin . "<br>";
echo "posted password: " . $submitpass . "<br>";
echo "database login: " . $db_login . "<br>";
echo "database pass: " . $db_pass . "<br>";
echo "database id: " . $db_id . "<br>";
echo "database user: " . $db_user . "<br>";
echo "database creator: " . $db_creator . "<br>";
echo "database admin: " . $db_admin . "<br>";
echo "database master: " . $db_master . "<br>";

if ($submitlogin != $db_login && $submitpass != $db_pass) {

    $_SESSION['ID'] = 'NULL';
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'False';
    $_SESSION['login'] = '';
    $_SESSION['pass'] = '';
    $_SESSION['user'] = '';
    $_SESSION['creater'] = 'False';
    $_SESSION['admin'] = 'False';
    $_SESSION['master'] = 'False';


    echo"failed";
    echo"<a href = '/wip/login/>try again</a>";


}

else {

    $_SESSION['login'] = $db_login;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $db_pass;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $db_id;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $db_user;
    $_SESSION['creator'] = $db_creator;
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $db_admin;
    $_SESSION['master'] = $db_master;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'True';

    echo "logged in";
    echo "<a href='/wip/>go</a>";

}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[you are at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)** is not safe! I recommend `PDO`, which I [wrote a function for](http://paragoncds.com/grumpy/pdoquery/#function) to make it extremely **easy**, very **clean**, and way more **secure** than using non-parameterized queries.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)** (`password_hash()` and `password_verify()`)to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). **It is not necessary** to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so _changes_ the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Also, please don't use the `root` db user

Comment: thanks il look into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending line breaks to the data from the database:

```
$db_login = $row['login'] . PHP_EOL; //<--here
```

so you are comparing:

```
"pass" == "pass\n"
```

As mentioned in the comments, you have a number of other issues, but this is the root cause of you problem

Comment: But PHP_EOL depends in operating systems.. in LInux it holds '/n' in windows it holds 'r\n'

Comment: @RaymondNijland well yes, that is true, i am only illustrating the problem :-)